# Javascript: Go to previous/next page

Tags: javascript, html, css

Assume I have three html pages: Page 1, Page 2 and Page 3. When I click NEXT on Page 1, it goes to Page 2, when I click next on Page 2 it goes to Page 3, when I click next on Page 3, it goes to Page 1. And vice versa for PREVIOUS when I click PREVIOUS on Page 3, it goes to 2; on 2 it goes to 1; on 1 it goes to 3. Now say I want to add Page 4. Instead of having to go into the HTML pages and change the link NEXT on Page 3 to go to Page 4 and PREVIOUS on Page 1 to go to Page 4, is there some sort of script (Javascript) I can write so when you click next, it automatically looks at the page number and incrememnts or else goes to Page 1 and vice versa for clicking previous? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you add some code, or show some kind of effort which you tried?

Comment: Today you are going to learn about the mighty modulo operator

Comment: These are HTML pages?? Then No. There is no way to do so. If it's a dynamically generated pagination then it can be done though.

Comment: @younis its also possible for html pages

Comment: @AbdulJabbar how will you do it? How will javascript tell you the number of html pages in the directory?

Comment: @younis: Yes, indeed, you'd have to have the count as a constant in the pages, and the pages would have to know their number (by name -- `page1.html` -- or with another constant).

Comment: @younis There is not a necessity for it to be DB driven, If no. of pages are limited and he is ready to tell it by writing to JS then he can do it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder , @Sanuj  yes i know. but he said: I shouldn't have to change the code every time I add a new page.
But again I guess its possible if the `count` is set in an external js file and `pagenumber` in every page.

Comment: @younis Ok, I assumed For minimum changes, Instead of NO changes at all.
For what NO changes at all, I agree with you it's not at all possible only with HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The general formula for incrementing a number whose minimum value should be `1` and maximum value should be `X` is:

```
n = (n % X) + 1;
```

The general formula for *decrementing* that number is:

```
n = ((n + X + 1) % X) + 1;
```

So if `n` is the current page number, and `X` is `3` (for three pages)...

Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/pepixu/1/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btnPrev" value="Previous">
  <input type="button" id="btnNext" value="Next">
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var page = 1;
    var pageCount = 3;

    display("Starting page: " + page);
    document.getElementById("btnPrev").onclick = function() {
      page = ((page + pageCount + 1) % pageCount) + 1;
      display("previous, page now " + page);
    };
    document.getElementById("btnNext").onclick = function() {
      page = (page % pageCount) + 1;
      display("next, page now " + page);
    };

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the trick is now converting this to a link. So that when next is clicked, it actually goes to a document called "Page 2.html". How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can better do it with array of page names - Given there are limited number of pages.

Like: -

```
var pageArray = ["page1.html", "page2.html","page3.html"];
function next(){
    var hr = window.location.href.splitOnLast("/");
    var page=hr[1].replace("/","");
    var nxtIndex =  pageArray.indexOf(page) + 1 ;
    if(nxtIndex > pageArray.length) nxtIndex=0;
    var redirect = hr[0]+"/"+pageArray[nxtIndex];
    window.location.href=redirect;
}
function prev(){
    var hr = window.location.href.splitOnLast("/");
    var page=hr[1].replace("/","");
    var nxtIndex =  pageArray.indexOf(page) - 1 ;
    if(nxtIndex < 0) nxtIndex=pageArray.length-1;
    var redirect = hr[0]+"/"+pageArray[nxtIndex];
    window.location.href=redirect;
}
```

By using this method, You are not bound to use strict numbering and free to add new pages anywhere in the list.

Also advantage of this method is that you can develop it further and use anywhere in your different projects including completely Database driven Menus, site, and navigation system.

The only disadvantage of this method is it can revel all the names of the pages in you current navigation in one go to anybody who knows JavaScript, although we are never intended to hide our page names form our end users.

**Edit**
I had forgotten to add "/" in the redirect code.

Comment: I am having trouble applying this code to my html document. Could you please show me a working example?

Comment: Please Give **details** while posting, It will help us to provide you with proper answer.

It would be great help if you had also provided what problem you were facing.
I have updated the answer please check.